# RTF document on Quick Look - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, rtf, migradoc

I have some RTF documents, created with the MigraDoc Foundation (included with PDFsharp), which include tables. I'm trying to open them from the iPhone using UIWebView and QuickLook but in both cases it returns only the first page and crapped.

I tried to preview the same RTF file using the Mail app and it show me the same result. The Quick Look on Mac shows the document in its correct format.Do you have any idea how can I present this RTF document?

Thank you!